# Download full resolution video from Google Photos API

Tags: google-photos

I'm trying to get a link to a full-resolution video with the API reading the [Google Photos API documentation](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/access-media-items).

It says `concatenate the base URL in the following format with your required dimensions` but says nothing else about dimensions.

I'm using `${baseUrl}=dv` and I get a download link for a low resolution video but if I look at the video in the Google Photos site I can see it has a wider resolution.

Comment: I'm also trying to embed some google photo based video and I get either 500 responses or 320 px large video fragments yet ..

Comment: I needed the same thing but just ended up requesting all my photos from Google (https://takeout.google.com/) and I might stop using them forever after this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is currently an issue with base URLs for video files.
The `dv` parameter does not support specifying a resolution at the moment and returns a downsampled version of the video.

This is not ideal and we are looking into ways to address this.
You can follow along on our issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/80149160

Comment: Apparently 6 months later you are still looking. Hope you find a way.

Comment: Apparently 6 years later you are still looking. Hope you find a way.